# Vectorize Hoeffding's distance

Tags: r, vectorization

I am trying to vectorise the following function which calculates the Hoeffdings distance between two random variable on [0,1]^2, in a discretise way.

Indeed, if you use the `hoeffd` function from the `Hmisc` package, it provides you with a fortran implementation ( that you can find here : https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/src/hoeffd.f ), but only give back the *maximum* of the matrix i'm trying to analyse here. I'm here interested in the *place of the maximum*, and hence i need to compute the whole matrix.

Here is my current implementation :

```r
hoeffding_D <- function(x,y){
    n = length(x)
    indep <- outer(0:n,0:n)/(n)^2
    bp = list(
        c(0,sort(x)) + (c(sort(x),1) - c(0,sort(x)))/2,
        c(0,sort(y)) + (c(sort(y),1) - c(0,sort(y)))/2
    )      

    pre_calc <- t(outer(rep(1,n+1),x)<=bp[[1]])

    # This is the problematic part : 
    dep <- t(sapply(bp[[2]],function(bpy){
        colMeans(pre_calc*(y<=bpy))
    }))

    rez <- abs(dep-indep)
    return(rez)
}
```

To use it, consider the folloiwing exemple :

```r
library(copula)
# for 10 values, it's fast enough, but for 1000 it takes a lot of time..
x = pobs(rnorm(10),ties.method = "max")
y = pobs(rnorm(10),ties.method = "max")
hoeffding_D(x,y)
```

I already suppressed a first sapply via the use of the `outer` function, but i cant get rid of the other. The issue is that the comparaison `x<=bpx` must be done for all `x` and for all `bpx`, and the same for `y`, altogether this is a lot of dimensions to the problem...

Do you have an idea on how to speed it up ?

Comment: Could you please post a link to the formula for this distance?

Comment: Of course. You can find the original article of Hoeffding there : https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177730150 and i believe on the second page, just before defining the delta-functional he defines a function $D(x,y)$. (beggining of the 3. point)

Of course, the function defined by Hoeffding is continuous on all the domain of the bivariate distribution function. Here, i'm in a particular case : By distribution functions are only discrete (and not continuous, hence the breakpoint things), and they are on [0,1]^d.

The information i want : "Where does this function D takes it's maximum?"